# CallKit Extension in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, callkit

i have a scenario like fetching the contacts from contacts framework and picking the selected contacts from the contacts framework and passing the selected list of contacts(array) to CALLKIT.

Once i get a call from any of the selected(which i picked earlier from contacts framework and passed it to call kit extension)...my bluetooth device has to vibrate(generally notifying the user)

i would like to know...whether we can pass array(selected contacts) to call kit extension and get notified if we get a call from the array(selected contacts) which we passed to call kit extension method

- (BOOL)addIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is definitely not possible with the current iOS 10.x CallKit API.   It appears to be a security/privacy thing based on how they designed things.

Comment: can you provide me any doc which says that it was not supported?